# VBA Consolidating duplicate rows and Sum a column with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I've had a look at multiple answers on the forum with how to merge duplicate rows in sheets and then sum the values of the duplicates together to leave 1 row with a unique combination of cells and the last cell as a sum of the duplicate values. Unfortunately I haven't managed to find something that works using a combination of multiple columns to determine if it's a duplicate that needs merging & summing.

As an example I've got 3 sheets - PreviousMonth,CurrentMonth and Difference that contain salary information relevant to the previous month and current month. The difference sheet needs to merge all the data from both the Previous and Current month without duplicates(I already have a macro that does this) but my Macro also removes all duplicate rows in both sheets before hand so if an employee claims more than 1 instance of overtime, my current Macro will delete any overtime rows after the first one.

An example is
Headings

```
Credit/Debit|Cost Code|Element|Surname|Forename|PayrollRef|Value
```

And the values in those headings

```
Debit|XXXX.XXXX.XXX|147 - R.Day x 1.5.|Williams|Matt|X|200
Debit|XXXX.XXXX.XXX|147 - R.Day x 1.5.|Williams|Matt|X|200
```

What I'd like to happen before my copy and paste and remove duplicates macro takes effect is to loop through each of the sheets, it can be separate or one after another and identify any duplicate lines for each of the employees in each sheet and merge the rows together but sum the value column. This is to handle the multiple overtime claims that employees can have in a month. Once it's done it there should only be one row of overtime per employee such as :

```
Credit/Debit|Cost Code|Element|Surname|Forename|PayrollRef|Value
Debit|XXXX.XXXX.XXX|147 - R.Day x 1.5.|Williams|Matt|X|400
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need more information to assist please don't hesitate to ask me as I can provide my other Macro's if they would be of use or more dummy data in the correct format. Unfortunately I can't provide the actual data in the spreadsheets though but what I've provided above is the same format of the headings and data.

(I know that there's a lot of similar questions and I've had a look at quite a few of them so if there's an already answered question that would do what I want/need already answered I'll happily go read that if you can point me in the right direction)

Edit:

The code i've found and trying to get to work on a concatenated column H is :

```
Sub Consolidate()
Dim ConsolidateRangeArray as Variant
ConsolidateRangeArray = Array("Sheet1R2C8:R98936C9")
Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("K").Consolidate _
Sources:=ConsolidateRangeArray, _
Function:xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
End Sub
```

When I use this code those it comes up Runtime 1004 error "Application-Defined or object defined error"

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Show your work so far and ask a specific programming question.

Comment: @Jeeped So far i've used the inbuilt Excel function to consolidate the fields based on a concatenated cell H2:H100000. I've concatenated Column A,C,D,E,F and then used the consolidate function on H2:I100000 and that has given me the consolidated results I desire. I'm looking for a VBA version of the excel function though so I can automate it as it's running extremely slow at the moment and is prone to not handing the 100K rows very well. In most cases not consolidating any data at all.If I try the consolidate feature with up to 20K rows it works fine.

Comment: Is the data at least sorted on all 5 columns to group duplicates together? What is the most minor deviation from 5 exact matches?

Comment: Hi Jeeped, The only difference between the rows would be the value in the last column. it would be determined to be a duplicate based on the values in the 5 columns being the exact same but the value for each row would be different. It should determine that the rows are therefore duplicates and sum the values for both of those rows. The data is sorted by reference ascending. The duplicate rows may not be together row. For the example provided the first instance of overtime was 3 lines before the second line of overtime so there's no pattern. Hope this helps but please ask more questions

Comment: ... and the PayrollRef would be some sort of unique employee id used by the payroll dept? That is, out of 100K records, you only need to look for duplicates within the contiguous group of a single PayrollRef?

Comment: Exactly, apologies for being so vague. The employee ref is unique to the particular employee and i'm only concerned with duplicates whereby the reference number is the same. So if employee X has 2 rows the same Sum those rows but even if employee Y has the same row as employee X it is treated as a new group based on the reference number

Answer (score 0):

I believe a Pivot Table would do the trick, you won't need to remove duplicates and all the duplicates will get its value summed, counted or whatever you need. That way you can have the same table as you have now with the values you want without running even macros.

I'd recommend to put a named range to get the source of the pivot table like that:

```
=OFFSET(*NameOfTheSourceSheet*!$A$1;0;0;COUNTA(*NameOfTheSourceSheet*!$A:$A);COUNTA(*NameOfTheSourceSheet*!$1:$1))
```

This way when your source table gets bigger, your pivot table will get all the new rows.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Damian but I figured out another way using VBA.

Once I'd concatenated the columns into 1 column I ran the below code against the values column and it produced the merged duplicate sums in 2 columns to the right

```
Sub ConsolidateFirst60K()
'
' ConsolidateFirst50K Macro
' Consolidate first row to 50K
'

'
Range("K1").Select
Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
    "'\\Filepath Of File \[WorkbookName]Sheet1'!R1C8:R60000C9" _
    , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
End Sub
```

It's a bit crude but it does the trick and I can refine it as I go along

I did find that using R1C1 syntax doesn't work over the 65K rows Excel versions sometimes have trouble with. Whether that problem isn't an issue with the more up to date versions I'm not sure. It didn't work in 2013 and therefore I had to duplicate the macro and change the ranges to be 60k-120k for the second half of the data

Regards,

Matt